# Mark favorite locations on a map and get notified when moving near them Android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, android-mapview

I want to develop an application that notify me when I get near one of my favorite places (previously stored by me). I will send my location periodically to the web server and get the near favorite locations while driving.

I will be using a navigator application in my car in this process. So the questions are :

- Can I use the built in navigator and add my favorite location at run time from an online database or should I implement a navigator app ?
- If I'll build a navigator app, How can I do this ? Using only map view ? does it support setting a head direction and it directs me to it.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an Android device. In this case, just use a proximity alert.

Have a look at this page of Google Maps API documentation:

[addProximityAlert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Google around for examples and tutorials.

You will have to add your POIs ("Point of Interest" or "favorites") to Google Maps in order to use them.

Have a look here:

- [Google MapMaker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker)
- [Add a POI to Google Maps](http://support.google.com/mapmaker/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1096044)
- [How to Import POI to Google Maps Mobile](http://www.ehow.com/how_6049577_import-poi-google-maps-mobile.html)
- [Custom pois with Google Maps](http://www.poi-factory.com/node/23691)

As long as I know, you cannot add POIs to Google Maps programmatically (sending a KML or a CVS file to the server) and you cannot keep them private (visibile just to you and your friends/customers).

For a better, more flexible solution you should use/customize an Open Source navigation application, like OSMAnd:

[OSMAnd](http://osmand.net/)

Have a look at the OpenStreetMaps project's wiki, as well:

- [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)
- [OpenStreetMap Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page)